# Why is TreeSet.remove's time complexity O(in N)?

Tags: java, treeset

A treeset is already sorted... so why isn't the time complexity to remove an object O(Log N) through binary search? Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that some implementations might actually consider rebalancing the tree upon modification, which can yield a worse performance. But this will only be necessary _sometimes_ and not always. Yielding a proper **amortized** complexity of `O(log n)`, while the non-amortized is maybe `O(n)` in some implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** O(log N) according to the [JavaDocs for TreeSet:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html)

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic
> operations (add, remove and contains).

Comment: Just a minor note, **some implementations** might consider rebalancing upon modification. Which can yield `O(n)`, while the amortized complexity is of course still `O(log n)`.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean operations like TreeSet.higher and TreeSet.lower is O(log N) as well?

Comment: @JosephJang Well, the Docs don't provide a specific guarantee for that.

Comment: @Zabuzard well, such an implementation would violate the contract, and should clearly document this. The OpenJdk implementation is based on `TreeMap` , which is a Red-Black tree and does not seem to do any O(N) operations in the listed methods.

Comment: Yeah, I was more referring to TreeMap/Sets in general, not necessarily Javas implementation. You are absolutely right that the Javadoc requires log(n) here.